# How to save control property from designer auto-filling?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I've made my control with a property

```
[Browsable(false)]
public IList<A> Prop { get; set; }
```

where A is my own class. And every time I run my project, Visual Studio tries to store this property in MyControl.resx and add next line in MyControl.resx

```
this.myControl.Prop = ((IList<A>)resources.GetObject("myControl.Prop"));
```

But this line cause the error

```
can't convert Orbis[]" to "Orbis[]"
```

How can I avoid this? How to say Visual Studio "Don't touch this property"?

Comment: Can't you just remove the browsable attribute?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, it's the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: @RobbieDee doesn't help.